# ASP.net core web API CORS issue with Angular2

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying a simple HTTP GET from my angular2 frontend as following:

```
  getGoals(): Observable<CoreGoalModel[]> {

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(this.base_url + 'coregoal', options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

I have set up CORS in my ASP.Net core backend. I have `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.1.1"` in projects.json.

My startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    services.AddScoped<ICoreGoalRepository, CoreGoalRepository>();

    // Enable Cors
    services.AddCors();

    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddSwaggerGen();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, WebAPIDataContext context)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

    app.UseMvc();

    app.UseCors(builder =>
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod());

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUi();
}
```

However I still get `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error.

What am I missing? For now I want to allow all origins, all methods, no restrictions.

Comment: FYI, you probably want to remove the line adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to your request. That header needs to be added by your server side code in its responses - makes no sense to send it as a request header.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence of addCors() and addMVC() was incorrect. addCors() has to come before addMVC()

Comment: Also note if you are using static files middleware you also need to put it before it. The requests are always handled in the order they are registered (the `:UseXxx` calls)